# Recovering/Repairing BitLocker USB

Tags: usb, partitioning, encryption, data-recovery, partition-recovery

I've found many posts on the topic of BitLocker, but haven't been able to find anything that solved my situation.

I had my BL encrypted USB connected to my laptop, closed my laptop to put it to sleep (and some time later), removed the USB and stowed the laptop. A few days later, when I went to complete my project, the USB is now showing as needing formatting. I figured that it must has still been doing some R/W processes when I removed it.

Now I still have the PW, but not the RP or RK info (I am still searching to see if I have the RK saved in a file). I tried using repair-bde to create an .img file and it seems to have been successful (reported 100% decrypted), however I cannot figure out what to do next. I checked our M3 recovery, and it does show all the data there that I need, but I can't really justify spending $150+ on a license for it. So I'm trying to figure out what to do now.

When I attempt to mount the .img that recovery recreated, I get the same message about needing formatting and/or the image being corrupted. Formatting and attempting to use Recuva doesn't give me the files that I need/want from the drive, and neither does anything else I've found so far.

So, at this point I'm guessing that the reason that the .img won't mount properly is because it doesn't have any partitioning data, but IDK. I've see things about using different software, and I've tried each, but they don't result in anything that I can actually mount without reformatting, and of course formatting then doesn't do anything.

### Additional Info

So I also noticed that M3 has an action that it lists as "rebuilding partition structure". So an additional question would be *how* I can go about doing that manually. I can see that all the data is there, now it's just a matter of ***how*** I can access it with Read privileges.

Comment: Have you tried Linux? Using the correct tools like "Dislocker", Linux is able to read Bitlocker encrypted drives. May be these tools allow to extract data where Windows does not.

Comment: @Robert I haven't yet. I don't have any linux boxes setup at the moment, so it's a little annoying to setup a box just for this. That said, the problem just seems to be with the partition table. It does successfully decrypt using repair-bde, but that still isn't accessible I believe from format/partition issues. The volume becomes inaccessible after dumping the data.

Comment: Use a Live-Linux DVD/USB stick or install Linux into a virtual Machine on your PC. For data recovery it is always good to have a Linux system at hand.

Comment: @Robert, I'll give that a shot. Do you recommend any particular distro for data recovery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PREFACE

Since I couldn't find this information anywhere when I was searching (and I searched a LOT), I'm putting my answer here. Now there will be at least one place on the internet that can answer this question for anyone (Power User or better) that comes across the same issue in the future.

No matter what, you ***must*** have one of the passwords for your BitLocker encrypted data to be able to recover it. The following information is ONLY to recover the data that I have a password to, which had a damaged partition. This will NOT help you recover anything without one of the passwords.

Finally, major thanks to [Robert](https://superuser.com/users/62676/robert) for putting me on the right track! Thanks!!

---

So, following the suggestion in comments, I *did* end up finding the answer down the Linux rabbit hole. In case anyone else comes across this, here's what I did to recover my data (if there are ways to optimize this process feel free to drop it in a comment).

### 1. Clone the data!

If you don't have proper write-protection equipment or tools, you can damage your data before you get it back. To make sure I didn't do that, I only worked on clones (.img, .iso .vhd and .vhdx). This way, even if I did mess something up, I wasn't damaging the source data.

The ONLY file that I found necessary was the .vhdx file I created from the drive using Disk2VHD (part of the SysInternals package). So the first thing you're going to do is to create and .vhdx clone of the problem drive. For these examples, I'll call this Lexar.vhdx.

Now, you'll need to make sure that you create another HDD (.vhd or .vhdx) that is large enough for all the data that was on your drive. You'll also have to ensure that the network is setup correctly so that the machine has the ability to get the needed tools. For this, I'll call this file Lexar_Dump.vhdx. **NOTE: Do not make this is the same size as the size of the original "lexar.vhdx" file or it will be a problem later.** The dump .vhdx file that I created is a true 128GB file, which was the labeled size of my Lexar USB. This will be big enough for EVERYTHING that it could have held, and it will ensure that the 2 main .vhdx files are different sizes.

### 2. Use Linux

Just as Robert mentioned in the comments, Linux did more easily provide the flexibility to repair the partition table and decrypt the information - without having to pay huge amounts of money for something I would use one time.

For me, I downloaded a distro of [lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/) to use (no particular reason other than it's very light-weight, so fast download and easy to run).

Rather than putting this on a USB or LiveCD, I just used the .iso as boot media for a Hyper-V VM.

Anyway, boot the VM to the lubuntu "livecd" (the ISO you downloaded) with the Lexar.vhdx and Lexar_Dump.vhdx drives attached as HDDs.

**NOTE: You MUST ensure that Secure Boot is *NOT* enabled or the VM will not boot from the .ISO**

### 3. Download the needed tools.

I updated, then had to use 3 additional tools:

- Dislocker
- TestDisk
- GParted *(optional)*

This was simple, just open a terminal and use the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y dislocker
sudo apt-get install -y testdisk
sudo apt-get install -y gparted *(again, this is optional)*
```

The reason that GParted is optional is because honestly, if you're compotent with the terminal, you don't need it at all. It's really just to check and make sure that the partition has loaded correctly, and to see the partition name that you need to point Dislocker to.

### 4. Fix Partition Table

Now, in my case, step 1 was to repair the partition before anything else. Even if I wanted to, I couldn't do anything with an "unallocated" volume. So I used TestDisk for this.

With TestDisk, (logging is up to you) the first thing you'll have to do is select the disk. This is going to be the damaged BitLocker image that you've mounted (Lexar.vhdx in my example). Since this is running in Hyper-V, you'l have most things labeled "Msft Virtual Disk" The way that you'll be able to tell which is which, is by the sizes. My original Lexar.vhdx file was shown as "/dev/sdb - 128 GB / 119 GiB" while the mounted Lexar_Dump.vhdx was "/dev/sdc - 137 GB / 128 GiB". So you'll select the original (in my case /dev/sdb) and press Enter to proceed.

Now you'll select the partition table type. In my case it was EFI GPT. (I say in my case because I'm not sure that BitLocker is *always* GPT, but it probably is.) After selecting the partition table type, select "analyze" and you should see something as a result. Select this, and press enter, then you'll press "w" to write the repaired partition table to the drive.

From here, if you had looked in gparted before, you'll notice that the file system has changed from "unallocated" to "bitlocker". If it has, you're on the right track! Otherwise, this may not answer you're issues. Now that the partition exists again, we're almost ready to begin decrypting!

### 5. Create Dump locations

So, now, you'll need to create and mount the areas where data is going to be moving around.

You're going to need 3 directories I think. 1 for the encrypted mount, 1 for the decrypted mount, and one for the dumpt mount. So I just did the following:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/dump
sudo mkdir -p /media/bitlocker
sudo mkdir -p /media/bitlockermount
```

Now that these exist, you're ready to start the key part.

### 6. Decrypt the Data

This is where Dislocker comes into play. Now that the partition exists you'll use one of the following to decrypt the bitlocker partition (in my case this was /dev/sdb1).

```
sudo dislocker /dev/sdb1 -u<user-password> -- /media/bitlocker
**OR**
sudo dislocker /dev/sdb1 -p<recoery-password> -- /media/bitlocker
```

**NOTE: THERE IS NO SPACE BETWEEN THE** "-u" **OR** "-p" **SWITCH AND THE CORRESPONDING PASSWORD. THAT IS NOT A TYPO.**

If successful, this will dump all the decrypted data into a special file in the /media/bitlocker directory.

### 7. Mounting Drives

This is the last thing before simply copy/pasting the data around (I realize there are probably better, more robust, ways of migrating the data, so don't take that literally).

In order to make the drives accessible, you have to mount them. I did:

```
sudo mount -t auto /dev/sdc1 /media/dump
sudo mount -o loop /media/bitlocker/dislocker-file /media/bitlockermount
```

For me, this correctly resulted in 3 devices now being listed, "dump", "bitlocker" and "bitlockermount". The "bitlocker" device will not be readable from here. You'll get something like this:[image: /media/bitlocker error]

You will however be able to access the "bitlockermount" device, which will now contain all the unecrypted data! :)

### 8. Move the Data

So, however you want to move the data is up to you. I just went with:

```
sudo rsync -avx --progress /media/bitlockermount/ /media/dump/
```

I'm not at all a Linux guru, so you'll have to decide what is the best way for you.

*NOTE: Depending on how much data there actually is, this could take quite a while.*

### 9. Wrap up with Linux

Once everything is copied, we just need to make sure there isn't any security on the files that will prevent us from accessing them once we're back in Windows.

So, to do that, we're going to run this on the entire dump directory.

```
cd /media
sudo chmod -R a+rwX dump/
```

This does expose every file, so if there were any ACLs before, they should be toast now. Make this accessible to you when you move it back to Windows, but also to ***ANYONE*** who may get their hands on the data - so take care of it at this point.

Once this has run its course, just shutdown the VM.

### 10. Mount the data in Window

Finally, you've going to mount the Lexar_Dumpt.vhdx file as a volume in Windows. Just open Disk Management Console, then Action -> Attach VHD and browse to your appropriate .vhdx file. If you formatted the Lexar_Dump.vhdx drive with a native Windows format, then you should immediately have access, however, if like me, you used the Ext4 format (face-palm), then you'll need something else to access it as Disk Manager will only give you the option to delete the volume! **DON'T DO THAT OR YOU'LL UNDO MOST OF WHAT WE'VE JUST ACCOMPLISHED!**

---

### EDIT

I found that Linux Reader was also going to cost money to use for mounting my Ext4 FS in Windows, so instead I opted to use [Ext2Fsd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/). This is the free option, but per the dev, it also has a little more disk involved, so I can't say this is the best option for everyone. Your best bet is to make sure that you choose a file system that Windows supports (just as NTFS or FAT32) for your dump .vhdx partition.

After this, I have my drive mounted, and I opted to use [FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/download.php) to ensure that the data matches across the new dump drive, and the partial data I was able to recover before, now ensuring that I have 2 complete copies of unencrypted data (which will soon be encrypted again.

---

<s>I just decided to use [Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) from DiskInternals because it's free, and didn't have the other risks posed by adding system drivers to enhance the Windows support base.</s>

---

Just for reference, here are some of the pages that I found in figuring out how to do this:

- [Using Dislocker for BitLocker Encryptiong](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/how-to-mount-bitlocker-encrypted.html)
- [TestDisk Information for BitLocker Partition](https://www.m3datarecovery.com/bitlocker-drive-data-recovery/testdisk-recover-bitlocker-partition.html)
- [Installing TestDisk in Live Session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix#Step_2_-_Install_TestDisk_in_the_live-session)
- [Installing GParted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053670/installing-gparted-on-ubuntu-18-04/1094011)
- [Mounting the Windows .VHDX Dump File](https://www.tecmint.com/mount-windows-partition-in-ubuntu/)
- [Create .VHDX from existing Disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd)
- [Disable SecureBoot in Hyper-V](https://trevorsullivan.net/2016/06/29/hyper-v-secureboot-error/)
- [Using Linux on Hyper-V for Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-run-linux-distros-windows-10-using-hyper-v)